# Actuarial problem finding the purchase price of a bond

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I came across an example problem that I don't fully understand.  Here is the problem and solution:

A 1000 bond with semi-annual coupons at $i^{(2)}$ = 6% matures at par on October 15, 2020.The bond is purchased on June 28, 2005 to yield the investor $i^{(2)}$ = 7%. What is the purchase price? Assume simple interest between bond coupon dates, and the following day count:
$$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
Date & Day of the Year \\ \hline
April 15 & 105 &   \\ \hline
June 28 & 179 &  \\ \hline
October 15 & 288 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We start by finding the price of the bond on the previous coupon date: April 15, 2005. On that date, there are 31 coupons of $30 each left and the price is:

$30*\frac{1-\frac{1}{1.035}^{31}}{.035} +1000\frac{1}{1.035}^{31} \approx 906.32$

Therefore, the price on June 28 is (note the use of simple interest for interim accumulation)

$906.32*(1+\frac{179-105}{182.5}*.035)=906.32*(1+\frac{74}{182.5}*.035) \approx 919.18$

This is a form of the flat price, not market price, and the reason why we use the flat price is that the question asks for the purchase price.

What I don't understand in all of that is, where did the 182.5 came from?

Comment: Half of $365$ days in a year.

Comment: Well, I'm dumb.  Thanks.